# Change file content using RegEx

Tags: php

Im trying to change file content but nothing happening.
There is only 1 word in a .csv file - moonwalk. Any help, please?

```
$fn = file_get_contents("test.csv");
$pattern = '!moon!iu';
$replacement = 'LOL';
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $fn);
file_put_contents('fixed.csv', $fn);
chmod("fixed.csv", 0664);
```

Comment: Read about the [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function. As all string functions, it doesn't change its arguments but returns a new string that you ignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) function doesn't work in-place:

> **Return Values**
>   preg_replace() returns an array if the subject parameter is an array, or a string otherwise.
>   If matches are found, the new subject will be returned, otherwise subject will be returned unchanged or NULL if an error occurred.

The result of the replace is returned, so if you need that value you should take if from the result of the function:

```
$fn = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $fn);
```